# How to determine $s$ maximizing the maximum root of polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, roots

I have the following problem. I have the
cubic polynomial
$$x^3 + (2 - 2 n) x^2 + (2 - 3 n + n^2 + n s - s^2) x + n^2 - n^2s +n s^2 -n.$$

In this polynomial, $n\geq 4$ is even, $2\leq s\leq \frac{n}{2}$  and $s$ is an integer.  I'd like to know for which of these values of $s$, the maximum root of the polynomial is maximized.

Since the root solutions of above polynomial are complex, I can't compare them directly.

Ps:
I used Mathematica and tried some 
specific values. **I found that when $s=n/2$, the maximum root is maximized. But I can't prove it.**
Any idea would be great for me.

Comment: Could you give more details thanks

Answer (score 1):

A numerical study.

Assuming a real root $x_1$ and two complex conjugate $(x-b)^2+c^2$ we have

$$
x^3 + (2 - 2 n) x^2 + (2 - 3 n + n^2 + n s - s^2) x + n^2 - n^2s +n s^2 -n=(x-x_1)((x-b)^2+c^2)
$$

and comparing coefficients we have

$$
\cases{
g_1 =x_1 \left(b^2+c^2\right)+n \left(s^2-n s+n-1\right)=0\\
g_2 = n^2+n (s-3)-b (b+2 x_1)-c^2-s^2+2=0\\
g_3 = 2 b-2n+x_1+2 = 0}
$$

now we form the lagrangian

$$
L(x_1,s,b,c,\lambda) = x_1 + \lambda_1 g_1+ \lambda_2 g_2+ \lambda_3 g_3
$$

Solving for the stationary points and particularizing for $n = 4$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
x_1 & s & b & c \\
 0 & 1 & 3 & 0 \\
 0 & 3 & 3 & 0 \\
 -2 \sqrt{3} & \frac{1}{2} \left(4-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{160+96 \sqrt{3}}\right) & \frac{1}{4} \left(12+4
   \sqrt{3}\right) & 0 \\
 -2 \sqrt{3} & \frac{1}{2} \left(4+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{160+96 \sqrt{3}}\right) & \frac{1}{4} \left(12+4
   \sqrt{3}\right) & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

for $n = 6$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 x_1 & s & b & c \\
 0 & 1 & 5 & 0 \\
 0 & 5 & 5 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{2} \left(2-2 \sqrt{21}\right) & \frac{1}{2} \left(6-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{248+56 \sqrt{21}}\right) &
   \frac{1}{4} \left(18+2 \sqrt{21}\right) & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{2} \left(2-2 \sqrt{21}\right) & \frac{1}{2} \left(6+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{248+56 \sqrt{21}}\right) &
   \frac{1}{4} \left(18+2 \sqrt{21}\right) & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

etc,

Comment: Thanks, this solution inspired me.